# gradle application plugin got shutdown

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am using gradle application plugin to run my application. Below is my build.gradle:

```
group 'demo.jersey'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

mainClassName = "com.example.Main"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.22.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

When I run gradle run, I can see my application is launched but it got shutdown immediately. Below is my Main class. Do you know how to block the application without shutting down?

```
package com.example;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {

    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example");
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stops because you invoke `server.stop();` explicitly so the program finishes. Comment out this line and it will keep on running and listening for incoming requests.

Comment: I just tried and it works exactly what you said. But what I don't understand is that the System.in.read() should block the execution until I input something on the console. Why doesn't it block the execution when I run gradle run command?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure. The problem might be that gradle and application run in a different thread and (somehow) and carriage return is passed to application which stops it.